# Message queue - No proper response

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

*I'm using message queues for sending and receiving messages but some parameters in the the structure msqid_ds no giving proper values why it happens?
    *Time of last message send=1525240214- why this is showing junk values?

```
        struct mesg_q
    {
        char msg_txt[100];
        long msg_typ;
    };

    int main()
    {
        int msgid;
       key_t key;
        char buffer[100]; 

        struct mesg_q msgq;
         struc answerst msqid_ds info;
     //  key = ftok("/home/yash72/krishna/thread_test/msgq.text", 65);
        msgid=msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

        if(msgid== -1)
        {    
            printf("msgget failed\n");
            return -1;
        }

        while(1)
        { 
            printf("Text Message\n");
            fgets(msgq.msg_txt,100,stdin);

            if(msgsnd(msgid,&msgq,100,0)==-1)
            {
                printf("Send failed\n");
                return -1;
            }  
            else
            {
                printf("Message send\n");
            }    
         msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &info);
         printf("Time of last message send=%d\n",info.msg_stime);
         printf("uid=%d\n",info.msg_perm.uid);
        }   
    }    

OUTPUT:

 Text Message
qwerty
Message send
Time of last message send=1525240214 // Why this is showing junk?
uid=0
Text Message



Receiver code:
```

- Reason for junk values from this code?

  struct mesg_q
      {
          char msg_txt[100];
          long msg_typ;
      };

  ```
  int main()
  {
      int msgid;
      char buffer[100];
      long int rec_buff=0;
      key_t  key;
      struct mesg_q msgq;
       struct msqid_ds info;

     // key = ftok("/home/yash72/krishna/thread_test/msgq.text", 65);
      msgid=msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

      if(msgid == -1)
      {
          printf("Msgget failed\n");
          return -1;
      }

      while(1)

      {
          if(msgrcv(msgid,&msgq,100,rec_buff,0)==-1)
          {
              printf("Mesg recv failed\n");
              return -1;
          }
          else
          {
              printf("Mesg Recvd\n");
          }
          printf("Recvd mesg=%s\n",msgq.msg_txt);

         msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &info);

          printf("Num:of bytes on queue= %d\n", info.msg_cbytes);
          printf("num:of messages on queue=%d\n", info.msg_qnum);
          printf("Max bytes on queue=%d\n", info.msg_qbytes);
          printf("Time of last message recvd=%d\n",info.msg_rtime);
      }     
  }
  ```

  OUTPUT;

  Number of bytes on queue= 0
  number of messages on queue=0
  Maximum bytes on queue=16384
  Time of last message received=1525240214

  what is the reason foe this incorrect values from struct msqid_ds ?

Comment: You didn't specify `msg_typ`

Comment: what msg_typ do with the struct msqid_ds?  msg_typ is in struct mesg_q. Answer for the question i asked.

Comment: You are sending whole `msgq` by calling `msgsnd()` second argument. You should update `msg_typ` value in same `msgq` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know why to use `message queue` IPC, I assume before using message queue, you have gone through `FIFO`. In `FIFO` what is condition for the processes to communicate each other ? that both process should be **alive** while communicating.

To avoid above problem of `FIFO` you are using message queue, as in MQ you can put data at one time and can read at anytime, for that you have to specify the `mtype` i.e with what `mtype` process_1 is sending the data and with what `mtype` process_2 is receiving the data.

From the manual page of `msgsnd`

```
struct msgbuf {
      long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0, I'm talking baout this */
      char mtext[1];    /* message data */
};
```

so in both the process(reader & sender) specify the `mtype`

```
msgq.msg_typ = 1; /*specify this in both process */
```

Secondly, *Time of last message send=1525240214- why this is showing junk values ?* => Its not junk data, its the time in seconds from EPOCH time, use `ctime()` to print in human readable format.

**sender.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include<stdint.h>
struct mesg_q {
        char msg_txt[100];
        long msg_typ;
};
int main(void) {
        int msgid;
        struct mesg_q msgq;
        struct msqid_ds info;
        msgid=msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if(msgid== -1) {
                printf("msgget failed\n");
                return -1;
        }
        while(1) {
                printf("Text Message\n");
                fgets(msgq.msg_txt,sizeof(msgq.msg_txt),stdin);
                /* with what msg_type you are sending, you didn't mention ? mention it */
                msgq.msg_typ = 1; /* I am sending with msg_type 1 */
                if(msgsnd(msgid,&msgq,sizeof(msgq),msgq.msg_typ)==-1) {
                        printf("Send failed\n");
                        return -1;
                }
                else {
                        printf("Message send\n");
                }
                msgctl(msgid, MSG_STAT, &info);
                printf("Time of last message send = %jd\n",(intmax_t)info.msg_stime);/* use the correct format specifier */
                /* what ever time info.msg_stime printing, its not junk, its seconds from EPOCH, use ctime() to print in readable format */
                printf("uid = %d\n",info.msg_perm.uid);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**receiver.c**

```
struct mesg_q {
        char msg_txt[100];
        long msg_typ;
};
int main(void ){
        int msgid;
        long int rec_buff=0;
        struct mesg_q msgq;
        struct msqid_ds info;
        msgid=msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if(msgid == -1) {
                printf("Msgget failed\n");
                return -1;
        }
        while(1) {
                /* with what msg_typ you are reciving, you have to mention ? u didn't */
                msgq.msg_typ = 1;
                if(msgrcv(msgid,&msgq,sizeof(msgq),rec_buff, msgq.msg_typ)==-1) {
                        printf("Mesg recv failed\n");
                        return -1;
                }
                else{
                        printf("Mesg Recvd\n");
                }
                printf("Recvd mesg=%s\n",msgq.msg_txt);

                msgctl(msgid, MSG_STAT, &info);
                /* enable compiler warning, and use correct format specifier */
                printf("Num:of bytes on queue= %u\n", (int)info.msg_cbytes);
                printf("num:of messages on queue=%d\n", (int)info.msg_qnum);
                printf("Max bytes on queue=%d\n", (int)info.msg_qbytes);
                printf("Time of last message recvd=%jd\n",(intmax_t)info.msg_rtime);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code also giving the same output. what is the use of intnax_t there ?ialso giving the same output

Comment: Enable the warning flag and check. Compile your code with  `-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` . _This code giving same output ?_ what output you are expecting ?

Comment: Use `MSG_STAT` instead of `IPC_STAT`

Comment: Read man page of `msgctl()` it says `msg_cbytes` is non standard. Better use POSIX ipc's

Comment: why im not getting the correct values from the parameters in struct msqid_ds?